# Joomla Get Page Id

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to get the current page_id, user_id and date from a Joomla 2.5.14. This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
$foo = $jinput->get('id');
echo $foo;


$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$usr_id = $user->get('id');
echo $usr_id;

$date =& JFactory::getDate();
echo 'Current date and time is: ' . $date->toFormat() . "\n";

?>
```

JFactory is working ok (I get the current user and date) but jinput is giving the error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: jinput in`
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to define `$jinput`:

```
<?php
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

$foo = $jinput->get('id');
echo $foo;

$user = JFactory::getUser();
$usr_id = $user->get('id');
echo $usr_id;

$date = JFactory::getDate();
echo 'Current date and time is: ' . $date->toFormat() . "\n";

?>
```

On a side note, you don't need to use `&`.

Hope this helps